# How to enter a dollar amount with puppeteer?

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

I'm currently working on a script with puppeteer to automatically log me into PayPal and send a desired dollar amount to a person. I have successfully gotten the script to log me in and redirect itself to the specified page where the dollar amount will be entered.

The element that is being focused is automatically selected when the page loads. I have tried different ways for the script to type in the desired amount shown below but haven't had any luck getting it to work.

The element that is being focused:

```
<input data-nemo="amount" dir="ltr" autocomplete="off" type="tel" name="amount" id="fn-amount" required="" class="ppaf-input ppaf-with-hidden-cursor" value="0.00" style="width: 86px; font-size: 42px; font-family: PayPal-Sans-Big, sans-serif;">
```

The script redirecting to the page before typing in the desired dollar amount:

```
await page.waitFor(10000);
await page.goto('https://www.paypal.com/myaccount/transfer/homepage/external/summary?.......');
```

What I have tried so far:

```
1. const cookie = {
   name: 'amount',
   value: '0.01',
   domain: '.paypal.com'
};
await page.setCookie(cookie);


2. await page.type('0.01')

3. await page.focus('#amount');
   await page.keyboard.type('0.01');

4. await page.$eval('input[name=amount]', el => el.value = '0.01');

5. await page.$eval('#amount', el => el.value = '0.01');

6. await page.waitForSelector('#amount');
   await page.type('amount', '0.01', {delay: 5});
```

The error that gets thrown is:

```
 No node found for selector: #amount
```

And the error that gets thrown while waiting for the selector:

```
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TimeoutError: waiting for 
selector "#amount" failed: timeout 30000ms exceeded
```

Comment: The ID looks to be #fn-amount not #amount.

Comment: @evolutionxbox I have tried #fn-amount after #amount with no luck still.

Comment: Make sure you only have one #fn-amount on the page.

Comment: @evolutionxbox I checked and there's only one #fn-amount on the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution:

```
    await page.goto('https://www.paypal.com/myaccount/transfer/homepage/external/summary?.');
    await page.waitForSelector('#fn-amount');
    await page.type('#fn-amount', '0.01');
```

Tried it on the [page](https://www.paypal.com/ua/webapps/mpp/send-money-online) but with id `#amount`.

Comment: So using the ID #fn-amount did help?

Comment: Thank you! I should've tried it without the delay in place.